# MVVM Закрыть/Скрыть главное окно

Tags: c#, mvvm

Как это сделать?
Если сделать Binding к Visibility, то это не помогает.

```
<Window x:Class="FiasView.StartUp"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:viewmodels="clr-namespace:FiasView.MVVM"
    xmlns:i="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/2010/interactivity"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:FiasView"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Title="StartUp" Height="293.698" Width="239.076" WindowState="Normal" WindowStyle="None" WindowStartupLocation="CenterScreen" Visibility="{Binding isVisible}">
```

Окно через ViewModel не получает скрыть. Как это сделать?

Comment: Управлять напрямую окнами из VM не лучшая идея, посмотрите в сторону контейнера и создайте класс, который управлял бы окнами, если у вас многооконное приложение

Comment: Мне нужно главное окно скрыть.
Вот в чем бяда.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Не знаю почему, но после перекура все заработало.
Прикладываю код.

VIEW:

```
<Window x:Class="FiasView.StartUp"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:viewmodels="clr-namespace:FiasView.MVVM"
    xmlns:i="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/2010/interactivity"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:FiasView"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Title="StartUp" Height="293.698" Width="239.076" WindowState="Normal" WindowStyle="None" WindowStartupLocation="CenterScreen" Visibility="{Binding isVisible, Mode=TwoWay}">
```

ViewModel:

```
 private Visibility _isvisible;
        public Visibility isVisible
        {
            get { return _isvisible; }
            set
            {
                _isvisible = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("isVisible");
            }
        }
        async public void LoadStartUp(ViewModel vm)
        {
            _lat = new LoadAllTable();
            _mv = new MainWindow();

            await Task.Run(new Action(() =>
            {
                _lat.LoadAllTables(vm);
            }));
            isVisible = Visibility.Hidden;
            _mv.Show();
        }
```

Comment: Кошмар какой, это точно не MVVM, советую посмотреть готовые проекты

Comment: А где именно нарушение MVVM кроме того, что в методе я вызываю напрямую MainWindow(уже убрал это).

Comment: ViewModel не должна управлять окнами вообще